# Keep allocation history after deleting a user

Tags: php, mysql, database, redbean

I have 3 tables - user, book and bookissues

When a user is deleted I want to keep the bookissues associated with the user (for book records). I also want to know what the users name and email was.

What would be the best solution for this?

Using redbean for ORM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a "soft" delete.  Make a 'deleted' flag in the users table.

Laravel has a good example of how this is done.
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#soft-deleting

Answer (score 0):

You can also use automated revisions to keep your main tables clean. Take a look at the rebean Plugin here
https://github.com/zewa666/RedBean_ReBean